# Spring data JPA Repositories + hibernate-types: how to use jpa queries to filter by arrays?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project with an `Entity` declared with proper `@TypeDef` annotations for `ListArrayType`. It works just fine: I can create entities and filter by other fields.

I have a table `workflows` with `responsible_users` field that is a Postgres string array. I want to query by this field. This raw query works:

```sql
SELECT id FROM workflows 
WHERE
    responsible_users @> ARRAY['urn:...', '...'] AND 
    responsible_users <@ ARRAY['urn:...', '...'];
```

But I'm not able to execute a similar query with the query annotation:

```kotlin
@Query("""
    SELECT w.* from workflows w 
    WHERE 
            w.project_origin = :projectOrigin 
        AND
            w.responsible_users @> ARRAY[:responsibleUsers] AND
            w.responsible_users <@ ARRAY[:responsibleUsers]
""", nativeQuery = true)
fun blabla(
    @Param("projectOrigin") projectOrigin: String,
    @Param("responsibleUsers") responsibleUsers: List<String>
) : List<Workflow>
```

because after the interpolation the query looks like:

```sql
SELECT w.* from workflows w
WHERE
        w.project_origin = $1
    AND
        w.responsible_users @> ARRAY[($2)] AND
        w.responsible_users <@ ARRAY[($3)]
```

How should I pass the list? Is it possible with Spring Data JPA Repositories?

### EDIT 1

I've executed the query manually:

```kotlin
@Autowired
lateinit var em: EntityManager

fun findWorkflowByProjectOriginAndResponsibleUsers(
    projectOrigin: String,
    responsibleUsers: Collection<String>
): Workflow? {
    val searchArray = "{" + responsibleUsers.joinToString(",") + "}"

    @Language("PostgreSQL")
    val query = """
        SELECT w.* from workflows w
        WHERE
            w.project_origin = :projectOrigin
        AND
            w.responsible_users @> CAST(:qwe as text[]) AND
            w.responsible_users <@ CAST(:qwe as text[])
    """.trimIndent()
    return em.createNativeQuery(
        query,
        Workflow::class.java
    )
        .setParameter("projectOrigin", projectOrigin)
        .setParameter(
            "qwe",
            searchArray
            // TypedParameterValue(StringArrayType.INSTANCE, workflowCreateDTO.responsibleUsers.toTypedArray())
        )
        .singleResult as Workflow?
}
```

Anyways, it does not seem to be an answer, because it's 2020.

(BTW, the trick with StringArrayType didn't work)